# assign individual formatted output parameters into variables (or array) - PHP

Tags: php, datetime, format

I have the output of a time difference displayed using the following code:

```
$interval = $timenow->diff($datatime);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
```

An example displayed output is:

```
0 years 0 months 2 days 9 hours 22 minutes 46 seconds
```

I would like to assign the individual values displayed into variables so as to do some calculations on those variables. (I don't only just want to display the values), I would like to assign, say:
$years = y,  $months = m, and so on, so that I can work with the year, month, minutes and seconds as variables.

How might I do this?

Comment: I recommend you to use Carbon and diffAsCarbonInterval() function https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval

Comment: thanks - will check it out

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you wouldn't want to use the properties of the interval for this? E.g. `$interval->y` for years.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply format your variable into individual variables like so:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime(); // Any DateTime object, this is using the current date and time as an example. 

$year = $dateTime->format('Y');
$month = $dateTime->format('m');
$hour = $dateTime->format('h');
$minute = $dateTime->format('i');
$second = $dateTime->format('s');
```

Comment: Thanks - but that captures the current time as individual variables. I want the time difference results as variables.

Comment: Then simply put the difference in a variable first?

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to create the variables manually. All these values are already available to you inside your `$interval` object. The [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class (which is the return type of `diff`) specifies properties:

```
/* Properties */
public int $y ;
public int $m ;
public int $d ;
public int $h ;
public int $i ;
public int $s ;
public float $f ;
public int $invert ;
public mixed $days ;
```

where `$y`, `$m`, `$d`, `$h`, `$i` and `$s` hold the values you need (from years to seconds). Thus, you can simply evoke the property you need (for example, `$interval->m` to get the months value).